# Why is the function printing the first two lines before calling it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return

Very new to python and I'm learning about defining and calling functions.

When `def function4(x):` and then define its output as a variable `m`, it prints the first two lines of the function before I even call it. Then when I call the function it only displays the `return` value. I was under the impression that anything indented under `def function4(x):` would not be executed unless `function4(x)` was specifically called?

Example:

```
def function4(x):
    print(x)
    print("still in this function")
    return 3*x

m = function4(5)

print("BREAK")
print(m)
```

Output:

```
    5
    still in this function
    BREAK
    15

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: But... you did call it, right there: `m = function4(5)`

Comment: Yea, C.Nivs answered it for me and helped me understand my mistake. Thank you for your input, I appreciate this community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the function will not execute until you call it. You are calling it, though, right here:

```py
m = function4(5)
```

So your print statements are executing in exactly the right place. You are setting `m` to the value returned by `function4(5)`.

`print` does not call anything. It simply prints the string representation of whatever you give it to the console:

```py
# a simple function to demonstrate
def f(x):
    print("I am ", x)
    return x

# I have not called f yet
print('Hello! ')

# I have printed the *function* f, but I still have not called it
# note the lack of parentheses
print('Here is a function: ', f)

print('We will call it now!')

# *Now* I am calling the function, as noted by the parentheses
x = f(1)

print('I have returned a value to x: ', x)
```

Which will do the following:

```
Hello!
Here is a function:  <function f at 0x7fa958141840>
We will call it now!
I am  1
I have returned a value to x:  1
```

Comment: Ok so maybe that's what I'm not getting. I thought by adding `m = function4(5)` that was just saying `m` will now be the output of `function4(5)`. I was under the perception that the only way to call `m` would be something like I did below: `print(m)`.

Comment: It does do exactly that, I think you're just putting where the function is called in the wrong place. By doing `m = function4(5)`, you assign the name `m` to the value `function4(5)`, which evaluates to `15`. This happens during the assignment to `m`

Comment: Okay, so that's where I'm confused. I thought I was **only** setting the `m` variable when I typed `m = function4(5)` I didn't realize I was calling it _and_ setting it as a variable at the same time.

Comment: Yep! The only way to invoke a function is with parentheses. If you wanted `m` to be callable, you could do something like `m = function4`, because that would *not* call the function, so now `m` is another name for `function4`, giving you the ability to do `m(5)`, again, evaluating to `15`

Comment: Ahhh! There it is! Okay okay, I got it now! I just needed a little grease on the wheels to get 'em turning. I accidentally called the function when I should've just set the variable to the function name (without invoking it). Thank you very much, that's exactly what I wasn't understanding! You are my 3/28/20 hero of the day! I'm too new to the community to give you an upvote, but please know that I did!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I strongly recommend you that you use http://pythontutor.com/javascript.html#mode=edit if you want to know how your code is working, is very useful if you are new on Python.

Then, as for your code, you are calling the function when you declare the `m` variable, so that's the reason why the two `print` statements appear first.
The return value will only appear if you print the function, that's why the number 15 appears after all because you've printed it when you wrote `print(m)`.

Hope this can help you, Goobye then and goodluck!.

Comment: Also, I didn't realize that `print(m)` would only display the `return` part of the function. Thank you for that.